# Websocket endpoints exposition / contract generation

Tags: java, websocket, datacontract, endpoint, discovery

I am experienced with web services but new with web sockets.

With web services, we can generate wadl or wsdl to expose web services methods.

Is there something similar for web sockets?

My web sockets are in java. Are there special annotations to expose methods ?

Comment: You may watch this [SOAP and/or REST and/or WebSocket](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=B-ElrhYxPQU) presentation.

Comment: I've created something called "wsadl" for project Tyrus (JSR 356 RI). It is experimental a does not expose much in terms of info (because lots of the configuration can be changed in the runtime). You can check that out at: https://github.com/tyrus-project/tyrus/blob/master/tests/e2e/non-deployable/src/test/java/org/glassfish/tyrus/test/e2e/non_deployable/WsadlTest.java and if you want, please let us know whether you can use this feature as it is or if you'd like that to be improved (users@tyrus.java.net). Thanks!